# How to reach else in if?

Tags: jq

```
if has("data") then
.data
else
"xxxx"
end
```

The second command below does not have any output. But I'd expect to see "xxxx". Could anybody show me how to fix the jq code that the else branch can be used? Thanks.

```
$ jq -r -f x.jq <<< '{"data": 42}'
42
$ jq -r -f x.jq < /dev/null
```

Comment: It is now fixed.

Answer (score 2):

jq programs are always filters. The maxim “No input, no output.” properly understood, always holds, though you might be able to achieve whatever it is you really want by using the -n option, e.g. using `inputs`:

```
jq -n '(inputs | if ... end) // "xxxx"'
```

Note: the -n option in effect provides the JSON value `null` as the input to the jq program. It does not mean “provide no input”.

Comment: I don't understand this. Could you show a complete working command using `-n` instead of just place-holders. Also, the purpose of my original question is about how to deal with illegal input (empty input being one, but there could be other illegal inputs). How to generally make `jq` fail upon all illegal input unless there is a "data" key whose value is not `null`.

Comment: Once again, you are expanding the question after it has been answered and after it has already received upvotes.  As for a complete working command, you can use your original `if ... end` if you wish.